# Django: How does it find the User model?

Tags: python, django

I have a question to the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model

The default value is `auth.User`. However, the actual model is in `auth.models.User`. How does Django find the correct class?

I am asking because when I usually use models in Django, I have to write `from myapp.models import MyModel`. So, why do I not need `models` in `auth.User` for `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Can some explain me that or show the code that uses it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you define models in the `models.py` file of an `app`. So that means that the *module* in which you stored the model class is `app.models`. Therefore the import reads:

```
from app.models import MyModel
```

Django has in essence nothing to do with this: this is how Python loads modules and classes from these module(s).

Django however loads - when you for example run the server - the apps that are located in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list of the settings file (usually `settings.py`), and thus constructs a "register" where it stores Django models, and it names them in a uniform way: `app_name.ModelName`. There is no reason to specify `models` here, since models are defined in `models.py`, and it thus would only introduce "noise".

You can obtain a reference to the model class with [**`apps.get_model`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model)

```
from django.apps import apps

apps.get_model('app_name', 'ModelName')
```

It thus then checks the registers of the loaded models, and returns a reference to the model.

Linking through a string is useful (and sometimes required) when there is *cyclic referencing*. For example if you have two models `A` and `B`, and `A` refers to B`and`B`through`A`(for example with`ForeignKey`s), then one of the two models is defined first. This means that if you define`A`first, it can not refer to the`B` class itself, since at that point it does not yet exists. In Django, one then specifies the model through a string. The Django system will then first load the models, and then "*tie the knot*": resolve the references by replacing the strings with a reference to the actual model class.